# xml reader not reading xml file and displaying in label

Tags: asp.net

This code is supposed to read from an existing xml file, and write the contents into a label, however, it does not work, and i do not know where i am going wrong. Help would be appreciated.

```
Dim reader As New XmlTextReader(Server.MapPath("~/ex01/docP.xml"))
            'declare variable to record when a <name> element is found'
            Dim bName As Boolean = False
            'iterate through all of the nodes in the XML document'
            While reader.Read()
                'look at the node type of each node'
                Select Case reader.NodeType
                    'if node is a <name> element, remember it'
                    Case XmlNodeType.Element
                        If reader.Name = "name" Then
                            bName = True
                        End If
                        'if node is text & previous node was <name>, add it to Label'
                    Case XmlNodeType.Text
                        If bName Then
                            lblDisplayXml.Text &= reader.ReadString & "<br/>"
                            'reset variable for next node'
                            bName = False
                        End If
                End Select
            End While
        End Sub
    End Class
```

the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<book_club>
  <book>
    <isbn>0-13-129014-2</isbn>
    <title>JAVA How to Program (6th Ed)</title>
    <author>PJ &amp; HM Deitel</author>
    <price>£39.99</price>
  </book>
  <book>
    <isbn>0-67-232238-2</isbn>
    <title>Teach Yourself UML</title>
    <author>J Schmuller</author>
    <price>£9.99</price>
  </book>
  <book>
    <isbn>0-27-365575-2</isbn>
    <title>Practical Business Systems Development using SSADM</title>
    <author>P Weaver, N Lambrou &amp; M Walkley</author>
    <price>£34.99</price>
  </book>
  <book>
    <isbn>0-67-232422-9</isbn>
    <title>XML Primer Plus</title>
    <author>N Chase</author>
    <price>£32.99</price>
  </book>
  <book>
    <isbn>0-78-972476-6</isbn>
    <title>XML and Java from Scratch</title>
    <author>N Chase</author>
    <price>£19.99</price>
  </book>
  <book>
    <isbn>1234567890</isbn>
    <title>ASP.NET for Dummies</title>
    <author>RUA Dummy</author>
    <price>free!!</price>
  </book>
</book_club>
```

Comment: Can you show xml file? also is the lblDisplayXml.Text is becoming empty after iteration?

Comment: Hey, posted the xml file. The label disappears upon viewing it in a browser.

Comment: You don't appear to have any elements called name in your XML. Does your code produce output if you replace `"name"` with  `"author"` or `"title"` in `If reader.Name = "name" Then`?

Comment: JAMIE YOU FREGGIN GENIUS! THANK YOU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no < name>  element in your xml, thus label is never assigning any value.

Comment: check your xml there is no name element